# How to read second array from json arrays in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to read two json arrays from same request
JSON FILE:

```
{
"items": [
  {
    "title": "welcoem home",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
  },
  {
    "title": "Harry Potter",
    "author": "J rowling"
  }]
}
{
"items1": [
  {
    "title": "welcoem home",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
  },
  {
    "title": "Harry Potter",
    "author": "J rowling"
  }]
}
```

and the code I use to read is:

```
 //Convert JSON to String and gets our app version
    private String getJSON(String JSON_STRING){

        try {
            //Objects
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
            //Variables
            int count=0;
            String tempTitle, temAuthor;

            while (count<jsonArray.length()){

                //Reads Row by Row
                JSONObject JO= jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                tempTitle= JO.getString("title");
                temAuthor= JO.getString("author");

                //If our App found
                if (Constants.Title.equals(tempTitle)){

                    return temAuthor;
                }

                count++;

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Not Found!";
    }
```

but when I call to read the second table like items1 it says no table found?
I tried to add a (,) between tables but same, I'm newbie in both php and android so its hard for me to change the code, so it is any easy way for me, I mean any way to change less code to make it work, or I have to change my android method completely ?

Comment: Your `json` format is wrong. Correct it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way for me, @Michael Jaison answer works too, but I fount the easiest way, I just read all joined both json tables like

> {table1}###{table2}

then in android I read all file then I split string:

```
String[] splitedResult = result.split("###");
```

so I got to tables

```
splitedResult[0] = { "items": [...
splitedResult[1] = { "items1": [...
```

Then just passed strings to method to read it :) and whoala it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below JSON code,

```
{
  "items": [
  {
    "title": "welcoem home",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
  },
  {
    "title": "Harry Potter",
    "author": "J rowling"
  }]
  ,
  "items1": [
  {
    "title": "welcoem home",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
  },
  {
    "title": "Harry Potter",
    "author": "J rowling"
  }]
}
```

You can check the validity of your JSON code in any of the online parser such as http://json.parser.online.fr/